# Determine sub-polygon from line segments with known member connectivity

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry, planar-graphs

Test Polygon:

[image: TestPolygon]

---

Consider the following polygon as attached. Let the known parameter be as follows:

•Member to member connectivity, i.e. it is known that A – B, X – E, F – B, etc. for all the members.
•All the space co-ordinates (x, y, z) for each co-ordinate is known.

Note that we do not know which members form the sub-polygon(s).

Given this information, I want to find all the edges and vertices which make up each of the sub-polygons, or in mathematical terms:

***EDGES () = A-E, XE, EC etc. and VERTICES () = A, X, E, C etc.
CAL_SUB_POLY (EDGES, VERTICES) = POLY(A-E-X-G), POLY(A-G-D), POLY(X-E-C-G) and POLY(G-D-F-B-C)***

Please note that the polygon shown here is just one case for illustration. Could it be possible to make a general algorithm for n-vertices and k-edges.
I have looked into meshing algorithms like winged-edge technique, but I cannot find anything relevant. In most meshing algorithms, the technique is used to create a data structure which stores the info of all mesh given that we already know which edges make the surface, the technique is an effective method of storing and accessing that information.

Comment: You are seeking cycles in an undirected graph. Use a DFS (depth-first search). See, e.g., [this explanation (PDF download)](https://www.me.utexas.edu/~bard/IP/Handouts/cycles.pdf).